# Connecting to Admob with r

Tags: r, api, admob

Is there smooth solution to query data from **Google Admob API** into **R** environment? *(for e.g. similar to googleAnalyticsR package)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone ever is looking for an answer the solution that i worked out is to use `library(httr)` and `library(jsonlite)` which are general packages for managing API's

First set up your google app for admob and generate oauth credentials,
store them in as described below and authorize token.

Obtain Token:

```
options(admob.client_id = client.id)
options(admob.client_secret = key.secret)


# GETTING OAUTH TOKEN
token = oauth2.0_token(endpoint = oauth_endpoints("google"), # 'google is standard
               app = oauth_app(appname = "google",
                 key = getOption('admob.client_id'),
                 secret = getOption("admob.client_secret")
               ),
               scope = r"{https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.report}",
               use_oob = TRUE,
               cache = TRUE)
```

You can generate your body request in within avaible google documentation in here:
https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reference/rest/v1/accounts.networkReport/generate

I'am passing mine as.list:

```
`json body` = toJSON(list(`reportSpec` = list(
  `dateRange` = list(
    `startDate` = list(
      `year` = 2021,
      `month` = 10,
      `day` = 20),
    `endDate` = list(
      `year` = 2021,
      `month` = 10,
      `day` = 22
    )),
  `dimensions` = list("DATE"),
  `metrics` = list("IMPRESSIONS")
)), auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

Query your request:

```
test = POST(url = 'https://admob.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/YOURPUBIDGOESINHERE/networkReport:generate',
            add_headers(`authorization` = paste("Bearer",
                                                token$credentials$access_token)),
            add_headers(`content-type` = "application/json"),
            body = `json body`
            )
```

Finalize with some data cleansing and you are done.

```
jsonText = content(test, as = 'text')
df = fromJSON(jsonText, flatten = T)
df = na.omit(df[c('row.metricValues.IMPRESSIONS.integerValue',
                  'row.dimensionValues.DATE.value')]) # select only needed columns
row.names(df) = NULL # reindex rows
df
```